# Estimating counts (case number) by logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, case-control-study

The work we are actually facing is estimating case number of a particular health condition.

The classification of the case status (Yes or Not) requires at least one positive lab test result and one clinical symptom. We have all of those data for last year. However, we only have lab test results (positive or negative) for this year. We would like to use last year's data to build a model and estimate the final case status for this year only using the lab test results data.

Logistic regression is my first choice. It could predict the both of the probability and case numbers. But the challenge is there were four types of lab tests (L1, L2, L3 and L4) and participants only has been tested by one or two of them. I am troubled by the model building with those missing lab test results. I feel I should re-code the lab results. For example, NL5 = L1 or L2 is positive, NL6 = L3 or L4 is positive. But I start to doubt the choice of logistic regression.

Any advice would be appreciated.